# How Can I Allow Uploading PHP Files to the Server Without Executing Them

Tags: php, file-upload

i want to make users to be able to upload PHP files and download them without executing them,
 i need to turn off PHP for a specific directory **so it behaves as plain text**.

i tried this but is it a proper solution ?

```
RemoveHandler .php .phtml .php3
RemoveType .php .phtml .php3
php_flag engine off
```

Comment: You can also rename it to `.phps` ....... Just to be on the save side

Comment: for what reason ???? @user1464822

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can use a Proxy Script to handle this.

In your `.htaccess` file, you can redirect all the requests in the folder to change to this way:

```
http://example.com/uploads/myfilewithadminaccess.php
```

To

```
http://example.com/uploads/index.php?file=myfilewithadminaccess.php
```

#### Source of `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ ./index.php?file=$1 [L]
```

And in the `index.php` just parse the file and give the output.

#### Source of `index.php`:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/html");
    $filename = (file_exists("uploads/" . $_GET["file"])) ? "uploads/" . $_GET["file"] : "error.txt";
    $filecont = file_get_contents($filename);
    echo htmlspecialchars($filecont);
?>
```

#### Fiddle: http://codepad.viper-7.com/68FSIU

**Note:** You need to sanitize the inputs before you allow URLs to pass. So, people might inject `../`, etc. those should be taken care.

Hope this helps and it is perfectly fine.

Comment: @ДамянСтанчев +1 Have added the security note! :P But since it goes via `.htaccess`, it won't affect right? How can one send `../` directly in the path?

Comment: it will affect in that it'll expose files that you probably don't want to expose.

Comment: also note that you can make this kind of a script transparent to the user with mod_rewrite.

Comment: @eis That's what I said, using `.htaccess` you need to pass the parameter. Ah!!! Please to read the answer fully! :)